# Google Chrome does not show the back end error

Tags: django, google-chrome

I want chrome to show the error by detail but it doesn't!

[the way I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rejgt.png)

I want something like this.
[the way I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz7sY.png)

Comment: Are you running you app on localhost or did you deploy it anywhere?

Comment: you need to run it in debug mode....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have the server running.
Try opening your terminal on the folder you have installed Django.
Then run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And see if you can access it.

Additionally, make sure you have set up DEBUG = True in your settings.py file.